# How to generate list from selected value

Tags: php

Please, I need generate selectable list based on value from other list. I have function for generating first list.

```
function getCatList ()
{
    $result = getCategory ();

    echo "<select id=\"catList\">";
    echo "<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">Select category</option>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<option value=\"".$row['codename']."\" onclick=\"<?php if($options==".$row['codename'].") echo 'selected=\"selected\"'; ?>".$row['visible_name']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

and I need generate next list based on selected value from this list.

I try set variable when onclick or some other attributes but without result.

I suppose it's caused because PHP is server-side language.

Can you help me? I would like avoid JS if possible. Is there any option how can I do this?

Comment: how can you use php in javascript onclick event handler????

Comment: where is $options defined???

Comment: @SachynKosare AJAX is unsupported

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com: I'm sorry I don't understand you. I use html onclick attribute. You can see it in the posted code but it's probably bad. PHP, HTML etc is not my languages. I know only essentials.
$option is defined at the top of document.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot launch PHP that way.

If you want to (without refresh) generate a list from a selected value you need to use Javascript. The easy way is to use Ajax, but you can make something even with Javascript alone (in the same page).

You can for example save on loading some arrays of data, and then on select change the list or what you want.

Comment: Page can be refreshed it's not problem but a don't know, how autosubmit this value (form) without button respectively without my interaction. I suppose that for this action I must use JS, right?

Comment: for most of this yes, Js is the way... Ajax will be the perfect solution.

Comment: But server must support AJAX such as PHP or it's supported standardly as HTML?

Comment: Ajax is supported by client browser, it doesn't enter in game servers =)

Comment: So I can use it anywhere where is modern browser.

Ok, I will try to figure something out using AJAX.

Comment: Ajax is Javascript, so is Client Side ^_^ it works even with IE6 if i recall correctly

Comment: Is there some significant differences between AJAX and JS especially in security?

Comment: Ajax is a component of Js. Ajax make a call to a webpage and Act like it is a standard web call. I do not think there are difference, you can for security purpose, google it a little.

Comment: Ok, I google some information and write my function. Thank you so much for help.:)